# Flutter Appstore rejection for contains obfuscated code or selector mangling

Tags: flutter, obfuscation, appstore-approval

Some problem when submitted app on App Store.
Got a replied after review :

> We discovered that your app contains obfuscated code, selector mangling, or features meant to subvert the App Review process by changing this app's concept after approval to the App Store.
>
> The next submission of this app may require a longer review time, and this app will not be eligible for an expedited review until this issue is resolved.

Currently, I'm using :
Firebase Crashlytic,Analytic,Auth,Firestore,Admob

It's good on Play Store, its got released but not in App Store.
Any solution?

Comment: My app was also rejected because of this reason, and I'm suspecting Crashlytics to be at culprit. The only mangled symbols seems to come from that library, eg `__ZN7plcrash3BIT5async15dwarf_cfa_stateIyxE11apply_stateEjPNS1_28plcrash_async_dwarf_cie_infoEPK26plcrash_async_thread_statePK26BITplcrash_async_byteorderPS6_`

Comment: Actually those symbols were coming from HockeySDK. Do you use HockeySDK by any chance?

Comment: no, i don't use HockeySDK. I also suspecting Crashlytics, but now still waiting apple confirmation.

Comment: I asked for details and... they just approved the build.

Comment: same with me! they just approved. So the solution for now is : Just ask for details.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple rejections with this same message have been reported recently (April 2019). Unfortunately, the message is pretty generic. Probably, the only option is to do what they say (make sure you complain with all guidelines) and resubmit including this message at the top of the "Notes" section:

"This app was entirely written in Objective-C to just meet the functionality documented in the App 'Description' section. There are no obfuscated code, selector mangling, or features meant to subvert the App Review process."

If it is rejected again, then you have to appeal and ask for further details so you can make the correction.